# Why string termination not happening at null character

Tags: c, string, null, char

Why it prints null character in second string?

Declaring character array should automatically add null character at end. Is this dependent on compiler?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>

bool ChckStrng(char *str);

void main()
{
  char a[] = "hello";
  char b[] = "abc";



  printf("a:%d\n", ChckStrng(a));
  printf("b:%d\n", ChckStrng(b));

}

bool ChckStrng(char *str)
{
  int count[26];

  while(str != NULL)
  {
    printf(":%d:\n", *str - 'a');
    if(++count[*str - 'a'] > 1)
     return false;
    str = str + 1;
  }
  printf("end\n");
  return true;
}
```

Output1:

:7:
:4:
:11:
:11:
a:0

:0:
:1:
:2:
:-97:
:-97:
b:0

Comment: There is no such thing as `void main()`, please use one of the defined entry points instead.

Comment: this line: while(str != NULL) is checking against a pointer, what it needs to check against is the character pointed to by str.  So it should be: while(*str != NULL) (note the dereferencing of the str pointer)

Comment: this code block: if(++count[*str - 'a'] > 1) return false; is reading bytes from the count[] array, which has not been initialized, so the presence of a matching char with a char from the str[] is very low. (probably an error). and, this is adding no value to the code and should be removed. (especially after the 'while()' statement is corrected.

Answer (score 5):

You are comparing pointers here, in other words, if `str` is set to `NULL`:

```
while(str != NULL) /* str holds the address of a char */
```

You need to compare *characters* to the null-terminator, in other words, check whether the character `str` *points to* is the null-terminator:

```
while(*str != '\0')
```

Answer (score 3):

You are comparing the value of the pointer itself instead of the value pointer points to.

```
  while( *str != '\0' )
  {
```

Not the difference: `*str`, and `\0` which is a null character.

`NULL` is a null pointer not a null character.

Answer (score 3):

str is a pointer which holds the address *str holds the value

```
 bool ChckStrng(char *str)
    {
       int count[26];

       while(*str != '\0')
       {   
          printf(":%d:\n", *str - 'a');
          if(++count[*str - 'a'] > 1)
             return false;
          str = str + 1;
       }   
       printf("end\n");
       return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Pointers are different than characters. In 'C' null termination of character array is signified by ascii value 0 or NUL